# How to paint Weight Black to Weight Blue?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-paint, vertex-weights

My question here is how can I get the part in black to blue. (see the images)
I don't know exactly what the weight black does but I think that it disturbing the natural weight paint.

When I paint with any value or even 0.05, the Vertex works like was painted with 1. And I think is because that are the black color on.

The Weight Tool "Clean" expands the black, and paint with Brush:Mix with Blend:Substract (and other combinations) turns black also.

Paint in the parts blue gets the good results with varied values. Diferent in the black 0.0/1.0

For any more clarification about it, ask me please.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try switch 'Show Zero Weights' to none ...at least to get rid of the black.

[image]

I think 'Clean' might be confusing the issue...

[image]

I can't see your brush settings but I paint with auto - normalize on, and find 'Smooth' the most useful of the Weight Tools for fixing.

The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/index.html) itself is also full of good info.

Comment: Thank you man, but that was a mistake for lack of another bones.
When are no one bone weight in the mesh, turn black. And the weight just go correctly between 0 to 1 if are another bone "to hold" the part.
And I noticed too that in the middle of the bones always move at 1 value, so I've had been careful about that and I found the new ways and solutions to resolve my character and it's fine.
At least in the weight bones.