# Cannot Weight Paint Near Bones

Tags: mesh, bones, weight-painting

When I go into Weight Paint mode after selecting my model, I am unable to weight paint near the bones (black area). Also, moving the arm bone pulls the leg skin, despite the leg lacking weights (blue). This is possibly because my model has multiple components that would be weight painted separately. Is there any way I can fix this? It would be awesome if anyone could help me :)

Comment: Set Zero weights to None https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80091/how-to-paint-weight-black-to-weight-blue/80094#80094

Comment: @Patdog Thanks for your response! This solved the black region problem, but the arm bone is still pulling the leg skin (without the leg having weights).

Comment: Chances are you have weights still connected to a vertex group. You can check this best in Edit mode and selecting the vertex groups one by one. Still stuck? You can always upload your file here and see if the problem can be found http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/